# Calling a void function inside loop control condtion

Tags: c

I would like to write a loop with the following pattern, where `spin_lock`'s return type is `void`:

```
while(workersAvailable() && spin_lock(workQueueLock) && (!list_empty(workQueue) || spin_unlock(workQueueLock)) ) {
   ...
   spin_unlock(workQueueLock);
   //long taking work, with no need for a lock
}
```

Reasoning:

- I want to hold the lock as short as possible and don't need it for `workersAvailable()`
- I know i can write a function `int f() {spin_lock(workQueueLock); return !list_empty(workQueue) || spin_unlock(workQueueLock);}`, however I feel that there should be a better way
- I do understand that `&& void` can not work since `&&` needs two operands
- I tried `,` and it would not compile, besides I am not sure if `,` gurantess ordering of the operations.

**Question:** Is there any way to achieve this without an extra function and without moving control logic inside the loop body (i.e. `spin_lock(workQueueLock); if(list_empty(workQueue)) { || spin_unlock(workQueueLock); break;}`)?

Comment: You are micro-optimizing. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can use the `,` operator, it will discard all the left operands evaluating only the last one

```
while(workersAvailable() && 
    (spin_lock(workQueueLock), 1) && 
    (!list_empty(workQueue) || spin_unlock(workQueueLock)))
```

But in my opinion, you should write the function, it's clearer.

Comment: Does `,` gurantee a strict ordering of its operands? If so one could write `while(workersAvailable() && 
    (spin_lock(workQueueLock), (!list_empty(workQueue) || spin_unlock(workQueueLock))))` (hope I did not mess up the Parantheses)

Comment: If you didn't mess parentheses, that is actually what you need... I just wanted it to be clear in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with some simplicity?

```
while(workersAvailable() && spin_lock(workQueueLock) ) { 
    if (list_empty(workQueue)) {
        spin_unlock(workQueueLock);
        continue;
        }       
   // critical section ...
   spin_unlock(workQueueLock);
   // non-critical section
   // long taking work, with no need for a lock
   // You *could* break out of the loop here
}
```

UPDATE: (I misread the question, and thought that `spin_unlock()` was void)

```
while(workersAvailable() ) {
    spin_lock(workQueueLock); 
    if (list_empty(workQueue)) {
        spin_unlock(workQueueLock);
        continue;
        }       

   // critical section here ...

   spin_unlock(workQueueLock);

   // non-critical section

   // long taking work, with no need for a lock
   // You *could* break out of the loop here
}
```

Comment: I do like to keep my loop control code together; I find it easier to read `loop(condition) {code}` than `loop(condition) {otherLoopCondition; code}`, let alone `loop(condition) {moreCode; otherHiddenLoopCondition; code}`. I am aware that the later is sometimes the best solution but I try to avoid it.

Comment: IMHO the combination of `&&` and `||` , plus the needed `()` and resulting long line are harder to read && more accident-prone than a `resume-to-loop - continue` before doing anything harmful. (but this is personal, obviously)

Comment: Agreed, when I first asked the question I forgot to unlock the lock, so it looked somewhat easy to read, and I was just wondering how to call a void function in the condition since I could not figure out the syntax, in the end I think iharob s suggestion is best, write a short function and put that in the loop control.